# Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem when i want tou run a function from my controller its said "Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object".

this is my function named category from my web.php controller

```
public function categori($id){
    $cek = $this->mymodel->GetKategori("where kode_kategori = '$id'");
    if ($cek->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = array(
        "produk_populers" => $this->mymodel->GetProduk("where kode_kategori = '$id'")->result_array()
        );

        $comp = array(
            "header" => $this->html_header(),
            "navbar" => $this->html_navbar(),
            "produk_populer" => $this->load->view("produk_populer",$data,true),
            "kategori" => $this->html_kategori(),
            "footer" => $this->html_footer(),
        );
        $this->load->view("index",$comp);

    }else{
        show_404(); 

  }

}
```

and this the model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mymodel extends CI_Model {
public function GetProduk($where=""){
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from produk'.$where);
    return $data;

}

public function GetKategori($where=""){
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from kategori '.$where);
    return $data -> result_array();
}

}
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? i'm new with this kind of stuff.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the returned value from:

`$cek = $this->mymodel->GetKategori("where kode_kategori = '$id'");`

is not an object. So the method `num_rows()` does not exist in that value context.

Try using `var_dump($cek)` right before you call this method and see what the output is.

Comment: after i use var_dump this is what it shows: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["kode_kategori"]=> string(1) "1" ["judul_kategori"]=> string(30) "RTD Juices " } } it seems like it goes the way its supposed to but why cant i run it?

Comment: What returned was an array not an object, hence why that method failed.
So you should replace `$cek->num_rows() ` with `count($check)` and it should work as you intended.

Comment: after i use count($cek) this is what it shows:     A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= '1'' at line 1

select * from produkwhere kode_kategori = '1'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/genstore/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691. do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Although that's a different problem than the original you created here, to solve it just give a space before the `where` clause. eg: `$this->mymodel->GetKategori(" where kode_kategori = '$id'");`

Comment: it works :D thanks for the help and sorry for the trouble